# How to return a object on v-model on <md-select> component on VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-material

I'm using Vue material components and I've a select to pick a value. The case is that I get the primitive value (String, boolean, number) when user select a option, but I want get the whole object.

```
    <div class="item-select-grupo-insumos">
      <md-field>
        <label for="codigo-grupo-insumos">Grupo</label>
        <md-select
          name="codigo-grupo-insumos"
          id="codigo-grupo-insumos"
          v-model="formNewInsumo.codigoGrupoInsumos" // Here I would like get the whole object, but it get the unic value.
          md-dense
        >
          <md-option
            v-for="(grupo,idx) in gruposDeInsumos"
            :key="idx"
            :value="grupo.codigo"
          >{{grupo.codigo}} | {{grupo.nome}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-field>
    </div>

...
data() {

return {
      gruposDeInsumos: [{
       codigo: "G00032",
​       nome: "asdasd",
​       tipo: "products"
}],
      formNewInsumo: {
        nome: "",
        codigoGrupoInsumos: "",
        unidade: "",
        wholeObject: {}
      },
}
```

whole object format used on: `v-for="(grupo,idx) in gruposDeInsumos"`

```
grupo: {
codigo: "G00032",
​
nome: "asdasd",
​
tipo: "products"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the object as value in "md-option" ?

 this way the option should take the value of the object instead of a primitive.

```
<md-option
    v-for="(grupo,idx) in gruposDeInsumos"
    :key="idx"
    :value="grupo"
  >{{grupo.codigo}} | {{grupo.nome}}</md-option>
```

Comment: I believe that `v-model` must be a String, number or boolean.

Comment: `v-model` can be any kind of value, the `v-model` yo use on `md-select` should get the value you specify on the `value` prop on `md-option`

Comment: If I do it: `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected String, Number, Boolean, got Object`. I can`t use object on `:value`